# Listing file basenames in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to get basename of all files in a directory using Ruby. I'm trying to use this:

`Dir.glob(folder_path + '/*.rb').each{ |f| File.basename(f, ".rb") }`

However, this still gives me the whole path in an array. How should I write this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
 Dir.glob(folder_path + '/*.rb').map{ |f| File.basename(f, ".rb") }
```